# Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent and $B \subset A$. What is $P(A)$?

Tags: probability-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are independent can $B \subset A$? Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Independent means

$$
P(A\text{ and }B) = P(A)P(B)
$$
But if $A\subset B$, then $“\!A\text{ and }B\hskip{0.1em}” = A$. What does this tell us about $P(A)$ and $P(B)$? You should get two possible resolutions of the equation.

Comment: Oops, sorry, wasn't paying enough attention when I wrote it, was thinking of union rather than intersection. I'll fix it.

Comment: So P(A) = P(B ) ?

Comment: Not quite. You're missing something on one of the sides.

Comment: P(A and B) = P(A)P(B), so P(A) = P(A and B)/P(B) = 1? I'm taking B $\subset$ A. If P(A) $\neq$ 1, then P(B) = 0.

Comment: Are you taking $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$? Assuming the latter, there's a second possible resolution (P(A) need not be 1, but if it's not, then something else must be true).

Answer (score 1):

Independent means $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$. Since $B\subset A$, you have $P(A \cap B) = P(B)$. So the equation reduces to $P(B) = P(A) P(B)$ or $P(B)(1-P(A)) = 0$.

Hence you must have either $P(B) =0$ or $P(A)=1$.

Comment: @dfeuer: Parentheses contribute towards global bracketing.

Comment: Either $PA\cdot PB$ or $P(A)P(B)$ is reasonable, but $PAPB$ is not.

Comment: I am following Tufte by unreasonably minimizing my ink to data ratio...